# Closing the dialogue box after download complete in C# with watin

Tags: c#, automation, nunit, watin

I am handling the dialogue box with WaTin in my app and saving the file with Watin. But after saving the file and as download completed Another Dialogue box remains open With three buttons. `"Open"` `"Open Folder"` `"Close"`

I want to close this dialogue box as its download completed.

```
 FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler("Arslan");
            browser.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);
            browser.Button("Save").ClickNoWait();
            fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
            fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);
```

Please suggest any way out for this

Answer (score 0):

I had run into a similar problem and some of the things that I observed were

1. All the dialog handlers ran into problems when multiple instances of the browser were open. I rarely ran into problems when there was only one browser instance open when the test was running.
2. Unless the dialog handler was removed from the browser instance, it would almost definitely fail during the next file download attempt.

Also, you might want to try increasing the WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled timeout.

```
FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler(downloadlocation);
try
{
    Button button = browser.Button(Find.ByText("Save"));
    browser.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);
    button.ClickNoWait();
    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(40);
    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);

}
catch (Exception excp)
{
    /// Log exception message
}
finally
{
    /// Remove the dialog handler
    browser.RemoveDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under **IE7**. But removing the handler as *Ashish* suggests couldn't do the task if you are downloading several files because removing the handler will just skip to the next task and this will cause a error on the next iteration.
So the simplest solution is to configure IE7 to automatically close the download window after the download completes. This is done by unchecking the "Notify when downloads are complete" option on IE7 Under -> `Intenet options` -> `Advanced` -> `Browsing` -> `Notify when downloads are complete`.